# Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@3ed03652 returned null for URL... While deployin spring boot to Heroku

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, maven, heroku

I try deploy my application on Heroku, but have some errors which I can't fix
my application.poperties

```
    spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgres://user:pass@ec2-54-247-166-129.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/database

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = pass

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

my Application class is standart spring boot class for application starting

my pom.xml (part of it):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>spring</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.0.30.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Error which I receive

```
> 12:06:42.061  INFO 12352 --- [ost-startStop-1]
> o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter:
> 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*] 2017-03-10 12:06:42.488 ERROR
> 12352 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      :
> Unable to create initial connections of pool.
> 
> java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@760cf594 returned
> null for
> URL:jdbc:postgres://fqwebtafwgsgmp:17ff02102b2660162ce1b053ef28340dfa7cf4d71e14b4bf1b187a8ad7d36579@ec2-54-247-166-129.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/daapseha11ekml
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:329)
> ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
> ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]  at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732)
> [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
> [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479)
> [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
> [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
> [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.11.jar:na]   at
```

I would be grateful if somebody explain my mistake

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using `jdbc:postgres` in your JDBC URL instead of `jdbc:postgresql` (note the extra `ql`).

Heroku already sets `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable for you, so you should be able to remove your `spring.datasource` entries in `application.properties` entirely.

If you are not able to remove them, try:

```
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
```

If that doesn't work, it must mean you are not using the Java buildpack or something.

Also be sure to run:

```
heroku pg:credentials --reset
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really missed ql in the end of string)) I spent almost a day solving the problem and surfing the Internet to search the answer. Thank you!!!

Comment: Also a notice, you should have sslmode=require in your url for using heroku

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably your connection url. You have the valid username and password in the url.

Change your `spring.datasource` settings to:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgres://ec2-54-247-166-129.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/database

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = user
spring.datasource.password = pass
```

PS. I tried and connected to your db instance so I would change them ASAP.

Comment: Run `heroku pg:credentials --reset` ASAP

Comment: The username and password in the URL are acceptable. The problem is the `postgres` instead of `postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Boot: 2.3.4 and driver version: 42.2.18

properties

```
spring:
    datasource:
        password: ${RDBMS_PASSWORD:pass}
        driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST:ec2-54-217-213-79.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com}:${DATABASE_PORT:5432}/${DATABASE_NAME:dbName}?sslmode=require
        username: ${DATABASE_USER:user}
        initialization-mode: always
        initialize: true
        schema: classpath:/schema.sql
        data: classpath:/data.sql
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: none
        show-sql: true
        generate-ddl: false
        properties:
            hibernate:
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

attention to the url: jdbc:postgresql://

[image]